# Почему при получении адреса переменной(которая и так является адресом) я получаю другой адрес в памяти?

Tags: golang, указатели

Почему при получении адреса переменной(которая и так является адресом) я получаю разные адреса?

```
p := new(int)
fmt.Println(p)
fmt.Println(&p)
```

результат:
0xc0000160b8
0xc00000c028

Почему адреса разные? на что указывает &p?

Comment: адрес, хранящийся в переменной, и адрес самой переменной - логично же

Comment: `&p` указывает на адрес в памяти по которому лежит сама переменная `p` (внутри которой содержится адрес созданного int)

Comment: Второй адрес - это адрес переменной с адресом. https://play.golang.org/p/9xInK351qC3